# Bibliography failing to appear

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am using someone else's code to type the bibliography, I thought it would be a nice idea to see something different from my usual approach. I can always switch back to the safe path but this problem is blowing my mind and iI want it solved. The bibliography fails to appear. I have 3 files, one with bibliography one with the class and the actual tex.
  In the class file it is written:

```
   \newcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{
   \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={#2}, heading=subbibliography]
   \end{refsection}
}
```

And in the tex file there is:

```
\section{publications}

\printbibsection{article}{article in peer-reviewed journal} % Print all articles from the bibliography

\printbibsection{book}{books} % Print all books from the bibliography

\begin{refsection} % This is a custom heading for those references marked as "inproceedings" but not containing "keyword=france"
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type=inproceedings, title={international peer-reviewed conferences/proceedings}, notkeyword={france}, heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection} % This is a custom heading for those references marked as "inproceedings" and containing "keyword=france"
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type=inproceedings, title={local peer-reviewed conferences/proceedings}, keyword={france}, heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\printbibsection{misc}{other publications} % Print all miscellaneous entries from the bibliography

\printbibsection{report}{research reports} % Print all research reports from the bibliography
```

After typesetting Xelatex,Bibtex,Xelatex,Xelatex in that sequence the bibliography does not appear. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have `backend=bibtex` as one of the options of `biblatex`? Otherwwise you have to use `biber`, i.e., `xelatex, biber, xelatex, xelatex`

Comment: There is no `ydn` sorting option (unless you have defined it). It should be `ydnt` (year descending name title).

Comment: I am sorry about that I erased it. I am actually getting this now ! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \abx@aux@sortscheme
                       {ydnt}
? , if I add backend=bibtex as you said

Comment: The `sorting` option is `biber` only. You have to remove it, or compile with `biber` instead of `bibtex`. If you compile with `biber` you have to remove the `backend=bibtex` option.

Comment: This is most likely running `bibtex` instead of `biber`. But who knows? I vote to close as unclear.